# Base space is connected then are all fibres isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

I am studying about fibre bundles. If a fibre bundle is locally trivial then I understand the fibres are locally isomorphic. Also I understand that any compact Hausdorff base space cannot have a disjoint finite open cover for if I have a disjoint finite open cover then base space is disconnected. My question is, if my base space is connected, then are all the fibres isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Yes, fix a point $b_0$ in the base and consider the set $A$ of all points in the base over which the fiber is isomorphic to that over $b_0$. Show $A$ is open and closed and non-empty.

Comment: I understood that if $A$ is nonempty, closed and open then $A$ must be the entire of base space. But I could not get the direction where I should start to prove that $A$ is both open and closed.

Comment: Local triviality obviously gives openness. It also obviously shows that $A^c$ is open, i.e that $A$ is closed. If these (atleast the first) statements are not obvious you just need to spend some more time thinking until it becomes obvious.

Comment: Actually you essentially said in your post (using very slightly different words) that $A$ is open. You just need to think more about what the definition of $A$ is and how local triviality comes into play.

Comment: I obviously missed identifying $A$ is open. I get it now. Still wondering how $A^c$ is open.. also does the result mean on connected base space a fibre bundle is always a trivial bundle?

Comment: If a point $b$ is in the complement, then its fiber is *not* isomorphic to the given one over $b_0$. By local triviality, the fibers of points near $b$ are all isomorphic. Therefore…. And lastly  no having all fibers isomorphic and having a (simply) connected base does not imply trivial bundle (e.g. look at the Hopf fiber bundle which is $S^3\to S^2$ with typical fiber $S^1$; you can show this is not trivializable since $S^3$ is simply connected while $S^2\times S^1$ is not as its fundamental group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$).

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Appreciate your time..